# Fetch the ID to post in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need some help with my code as I have got a problem with defined the variable to post them in Ajax. I am working on PHP as I am fetching the data from mysql database to input the information in PHP, so I would like to post the ID in ajax.

I have defined the variable `$autoid` outside of the while loop, but I am unable to defined them when I am using jquery because it will show empty data when I try to post them in Ajax.

When I try this:

```
var ID = $(this).data('deleteid');

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "sendtest.php",
  data: {ID : "deleteid"
  },

  success: function(resultData) {
    alert(resultData)
  }
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mydbusername', 'mydbpassword', 'mydbpassword');
    $param_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $autocampaign = $_SESSION["auto_campaign"];
    $autor_sql = "SELECT id, subject, day_cycle, enabled, delaysend FROM auto WHERE campaign ='$autocampaign' AND username ='$param_username'";
    $autoid = '';

    $results = mysqli_query($link, $auto_sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) 
    { 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
        {
            $autoid = $row["id"];
            $autosubject = $row["subject"];
            $autodaycycle = $row["day_cycle"];
            $autoenabled = $row["enabled"];
            $autodelay = $row["delaysend"];
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">


.calendar-content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 112px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>


<div class="calendar-content">
  <div style="margin-left: 40px;margin-top: 20px; height: 40px;">
    <span id="autosubject" style="font-size: 25px;color: #0c7ac0;float: left;">Subject: <?php echo $autosubject ?> </span><br>
    <div style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 15px; height: 40px;">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <span style="font-size: 15px; color: #ccd5d9; float: left; margin-top: -1px"><a name="autoid" id="autoid" href="#contactModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">Send a test</a> | <a name="deleteid" id="deleteid" href="/auto/delete_auto.php?id=<?php echo $autoid; ?>"> Delete </a> | Copy to Draft | Settings</span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div><br>

  <!-- email Modal -->
  <div id="contactModal" class="modal fade" style="margin-top: 12%;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content" style="height: 250px;">
        <div class="modal-header" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Send A Test Email</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="height: 65%;">
          <form action="" method="post">
            <label class="label-control" value="">Send test message to email address:</label>
            <select name="emails" id="emails" value="" style="width: 400px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 18px; margin-left: 60px;">
              <option selected="selected" value='title'>Title</option>";
            </select><br>
            <button name="send_email" id="send_email" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 36%;" data-auto-id="<?php echo $autoid; ?>">Send Test</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#send_email').click(function(e) {
    $(this)
      .html("<span><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Sending...</span>")
      .prop("disabled", true);
    var ID = $(this).data('deleteid');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "sendtest.php",
      data: {ID : "deleteid"
      },

      success: function(resultData) {
        alert(resultData)
        $('#contactModal').modal('hide');
        $("#send_email")
          .html("Send Test")
          .prop("disabled", false);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here is the sendtest.php:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;

}
else if(isset($_POST))
{
    $id = $_POST[$autoid];
    echo "hello your id is...";
    echo $id;
}
?>
```

What I want to achieve is when I click on a send a test hyperlink, a modal will display and when I click on a button after I select on a dropdown listbox, I want to fetch the ID from the Delete hyperlink so I can post them in ajax. The reasons I want to post the ID in ajax is because I want to stay on the same page while I want to fetch the information from the mysql database.

Can you please show me an example how I can fetch the ID from the Delete hyperlink to post them in ajax?

Thank you for understanding what I am trying to do.

Comment: 1st: `data: {ID : "deleteid"},` should be `data: {ID : ID },` (you want to send the var, not the string "deleteid")

Comment: @Jeff Thank you for your advice, I have changed it but when I click on a send a test hyperlink that a modal display and when I click on a button, it will not show the Delete ID in the alert. Any idea?

Comment: 2nd: `var ID = $(this).data('deleteid');` should be `ID = $(this).data('auto-id');`, because the data-attribute is `data-auto-id="...`

Comment: 3rd: `$id = $_POST[$autoid];` will throw an error (undefined variable) & a notice (undefined index). Should be `$_POST['ID']`, because you call the param "ID" here: `data: {ID : varname},`

Comment: 4th: missing a `;` here: `alert(resultData)`

Comment: @Jeff Thank you very much for your help. If I want to post the username or whatever it is, do I have to use something similar as the ID? Thank you!

Comment: Please note that can you please post the answer so I can give you a vote and mark as the answer?

Comment: Yes, for a username just do the same as you did for ID.

Comment: @Jeff Oh right. I want to know how I can use the echo in the button to fetch the email in the select dropdown box?

Comment: @Jeff Do I have to use something like this? `data-send-email ="<?php $_POST['emails']; ?>  "`, for ajax: `var EMAILS = $(this).data('send-email'); data: {ID : ID, EMAILS : EMAILS },`??

Comment: jep, looks promising! _sidenote:_ don't get into the habit in writing all varnames uppercase. The standard is uppercase for constants.

Comment: @Jeff Oh right. When I try to use the button to send the select value from the select options, it will show the empty value when I click on a button. I think there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: for button: `<button name="send_email" id="send_email" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 36%;" data-auto-id="<?php echo $autoid; ?> data-send-email ="<?php $emails = $_POST['emails']; ?>   ">Send Test</button>`

Comment: for ajax: `var EMAILS = $(this).data('send-email');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "sendtest.php",
      data: {ID : ID, EMAILS : EMAILS },` and for sendtest.php `$email = $_POST['EMAILS'];`

Comment: `"<?php $emails = $_POST['emails']; ?> "` is wrong. should be `"<?php echo $_POST['emails']; ?>"` (also notice the space you had between `?>` and `"`)

Comment: @Jeff Thank you, I have changed it but when I select the value and click on a button, it still show an empty string in the post. Any idea?

Comment: the code you have now doesn't take any values from the <select>. Please search online for how to do that or open another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1st: `data: {ID : "deleteid"},` should be `data: {ID : ID },` (you want to send the var, not the string "deleteid")

2nd: `var ID = $(this).data('deleteid');` should be `var ID = $(this).data('auto-id');`, because the data-attribute is data-auto-id="...

3rd: `$id = $_POST[$autoid];` will throw an error (undefined variable) & a notice (undefined index). Should be `$id = $_POST['ID']`, because you call the param "ID" here: `data: {ID : varname},`

4th: you are missing a `;` here: `alert(resultData)`

Here's the corrected ajax-part:

```
var ID = $(this).data('auto-id');
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "sendtest.php",
  data: {ID : ID },

  success: function(resultData) {
    alert(resultData);
    $('#contactModal').modal('hide');
    $("#send_email")
      .html("Send Test")
      .prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```